# Eclipse PyDev highlighting text makes it hard to read

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

whenever I write code with the PyDev Eclipse Python editor, it highlights the similar code in yellow. Is it possible to change the color it highlights with so it's easier to read?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change that in the annotations (i.e.: `Ctrl+3, Annotations > Occurrences (PyDev)`.

As a note, if you're using LiClipse (which will manage the colors for you), you have to edit the theme (i.e.: `Ctrl+3 > Color Theme > Edit theme > occurrenceIndication`) -- or just select a different theme.